# Why is this probability independent of position?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I recently encountered the following probability question:
Given $R$ red marbles and $B$ blue marbles, we draw all the marbles from the bag one at a time without replacement. Find the probability drawing marbles in the following order: red marbles at positions $r_1,...,r_n$ and blue marbles at positions $b_1,...b_k$.
As a concrete example, suppose we have $5$ red marbles ($R=5$) and $8$ blue marbles ($B = 8$). What is the probability that the $1$st and $5$th marbles are blue, while the $2$nd marble is red?

The solution to this problem was given as follows:
We know that we will draw all the marbles, so we can create placeholders for the general case with all possibilities:
$$\text{_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _} \tag{1}$$

Then, we want the marbles to appear in our desired positions $r_i$ and $b_j$. Taking the concrete example from earlier:

$$\text{B R _ _ B _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _} \tag{2}$$

We see that the probability is equivalent to finding the number of unique possbilities in the specific case divided by the number of general cases $\left( \frac{\mathbb{P}(2)}{\mathbb{P}(1)}\right)$.

Looking at the equation $(1)$, we can find the number of the possibilities by thinking as if we need to choose $8$ places to place blue marbles or $5$ places for red marbles from $13$ places. As for the equation $(2)$, it is equivalent to choosing $8 - 2 = 6$ places for blue marbles (because $2$ places are already occupied at positions $1$ and $5$) or $5-1=4$ places for red marbles from $13 - (2 + 1) = 10$ places, giving a probability of $\frac{10 \choose 6}{13 \choose 8} = 210/1287 \approx 0.163$

In general, we find that the probability is $$P = \frac{E \choose R-n}{T \choose R}=\frac{E \choose B-k}{T \choose B}$$
where the number of remaining empty spaces $E=T-n-k$  is the total of marbles $T = R+B$ minus the number of already placed ones.

This reasoning shows that the probability is independent of the positions the marbles were drawn at, which are $r_i$ and $b_j$.

Here are my questions:

1. Are there any other intuitive explanations that can show this independence of position?
2. Is there a way to quickly calculate the probability that the marbles do NOT all arrive on those positions (so the complement problem) without directly taking the complement from the current solution?
3. For the case where not all the marbles are drawn $T \neq R+B$, I obtained the probability $$P = \frac{\sum_{m=\min(n,k)}^{\max(n,k)} {E\choose m}}{\sum_{q=\min(B,R)}^{\max(B,R)} {T \choose q}}$$ by using this reasoning. Is there a shorter way to calculate this answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**

Not an answer, just an illustration

**Illustration**

Say that we create an experiment to confirm your calculation:

1. Label $13$ boxes from $1$ to $13$
2. Put $8$ blue and $5$ balls into the boxes in every possible ways
3. Count the number of placements where box $1$, $5$ contains a blue ball each and box $2$ contains a red ball

Just like your calculation, you will get $210$ distinct placements. Now swap the label of box $2$ and $8$. This does not change the number of distinct placements right? But now box $1$, $5$ contains a blue ball and box $8$ contains a red ball.

Comment: Wow, that is a great insight. What about the case where the number is boxes is not equal to the number of balls? Is there a way you can use this to calculate it?